# Ubuntu taking too long to shutdown

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

Please check this log: https://pastebin.com/tNru5g08

Here are my some log entries:

```
>     linux@dell ~> journalctl -rb -1 
Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd-journald[291]: Journal stopped Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes... Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block
    > devices. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Shutting down. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off. Sep 17 09:42:18
    > dell systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
    > Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown
    > Services. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Reached target System
    > Shutdown. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and
    > Kernel File Systems. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18
    > dell systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /swapfile. Sep 17 09:42:18
    > dell systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users. Sep 17 09:42:18
    > dell systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated successfully.
    > Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in
    > /dev. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /swapfile... Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Stopped target Swaps. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: Stopped target Preparation for Local File Systems. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/snapd/ns. Sep 17 09:42:18
    > dell systemd[1]: run-snapd-ns.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounting /run/snapd/ns... Sep 17 09:42:18
    > dell systemd[1]: Stopped target Mounting snaps. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for firefox, revision 2277 via
    > mount-cont> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount: Deactivated su> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > wine-platform-runtime-core20, revisio> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime\x2dcore20-77.mount:
    > Deactivat> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > wine-platform-runtime-core20, revisio> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime\x2dcore20-76.mount:
    > Deactivat> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > wine-platform-runtime, revision 349. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime-349.mount: Deactivated succes> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > wine-platform-runtime, revision 348. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime-348.mount: Deactivated succes> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > wine-platform-7-devel-core20, revisio> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d7\x2ddevel\x2dcore20-24.mount:
    > Deacti> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > wine-platform-7-devel-core20, revisio> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d7\x2ddevel\x2dcore20-23.mount:
    > Deacti> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > wine-platform-6-stable, revision 19. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d6\x2dstable-19.mount: Deactivated suc> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > wine-platform-6-stable, revision 14. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d6\x2dstable-14.mount: Deactivated suc> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for telegram-desktop,
    > revision 5050. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-5050.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for telegram-desktop,
    > revision 5034. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-5034.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > snapd-desktop-integration, revision 8> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-83.mount: Deactivated
    > suc> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > snapd-desktop-integration, revision 5> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-57.mount: Deactivated
    > suc> Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > snap-store, revision 959. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-snap\x2dstore-959.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snap-store,
    > revision 638. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-snap\x2dstore-638.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for notepad-plus-plus,
    > revision 386. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-386.mount: Deactivated successful> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for notepad-plus-plus,
    > revision 385. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-385.mount: Deactivated successful> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gtk-common-themes,
    > revision 1535. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount: Deactivated successfu> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gtk-common-themes,
    > revision 1534. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1534.mount: Deactivated successfu> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > gnome-system-monitor, revision 184. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-184.mount: Deactivated success> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > gnome-system-monitor, revision 181. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-181.mount: Deactivated success> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-42-2204,
    > revision 126. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-126.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-42-2204,
    > revision 120. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-120.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-38-2004,
    > revision 143. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-143.mount: Deactivated successfu> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-38-2004,
    > revision 140. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-140.mount: Deactivated successfu> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804,
    > revision 93. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-93.mount: Deactivated successful> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804,
    > revision 90. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-90.mount: Deactivated successful> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804,
    > revision 198. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-198.mount: Deactivated successfu> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804,
    > revision 194. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-194.mount: Deactivated successfu> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-26-1604,
    > revision 111. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-111.mount: Deactivated successfu> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-26-1604,
    > revision 104. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-104.mount: Deactivated successfu> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for firefox, revision
    > 3131. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: snap-firefox-3131.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted
    > Mount unit for firefox, revision 3068. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: snap-firefox-3068.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for core22, revision
    > 864. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: snap-core22-864.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted
    > Mount unit for core22, revision 858. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-core22-858.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for core20, revision 2015. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: snap-core20-2015.mount: Deactivated
    > successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit
    > for core20, revision 1974. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-core20-1974.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for core18, revision 2790. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: snap-core18-2790.mount: Deactivated
    > successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit
    > for core18, revision 2785. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-core18-2785.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for core, revision 15925. Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: snap-core-15925.mount: Deactivated
    > successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit
    > for core, revision 15511. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-core-15511.mount: Deactivated successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell
    > systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for canonical-livepatch, revision
    > 235. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-235.mount: Deactivated successfull> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for
    > canonical-livepatch, revision 229. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]:
    > snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-229.mount: Deactivated successfull> Sep 17
    > 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for bare, revision 5.
    > Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: snap-bare-5.mount: Deactivated
    > successfully. Sep 17 09:42:18 dell systemd[1]: Unmounted
    > /run/snapd/ns/snapd-desktop-integration.mnt.
```

Please advise what's going on my system?

Best Regards

*****UPDATE*****
Here is my complete log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pq9l3H-Ll76cdB9Xl1lCJGAnAS63CaSs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Luuk please check some more log at https://pastebin.com/tNru5g08

Comment: Is there any hacking problem with my computer?

Comment: @Luuk I have copy pasted all my log here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pq9l3H-Ll76cdB9Xl1lCJGAnAS63CaSs/view?usp=sharing